# I am displaying amazon's website inside iframe, is it possible to read the price of products from there?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a iframe on my website, it displays the amazon's site in it. When the user click any on any of the product there, it redirects to the amazon site in new tab, I am trying to read the price of that specific product on which user clicks.

I tried to read the price of the product on which user clicks

Comment: Nope.  Security reasons.

Comment: Cross-site scripting can be dangerous, so browsers only allow it if the site you want to script has allowed your site to do this.  Amazon is not going to say yes  :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)